# get the original URL in PHP file from a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with about 100 pages that contain a link to a contact form that is on a non-Wordpress site.

Let's call my Wordpress site https://example.com.  Let's call one of the pages https://example.com/refinance-your-home-today/.

The contact form has the following code, which contains "https://example.com" as the original url (client_url in the code) about 75% of the time.  Using the example above, the client_url should capture "https://example.com/refinance-your-home-today/."

When I use the following code, the client_url value is NULL:

```
<?php

session_start();
function wp_get_original_referer() {
if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['_wp_original_http_referer'] ) && function_exists( 'wp_validate_redirect' ) ) {
    return wp_validate_redirect( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['_wp_original_http_referer'] ), false );
}

return false;
```

}

```
$_SESSION['client_url'] = wp_get_original_referer();
```

When I use the following code the client_url appears correctly only about 25% of the time.  It appears about 75% of the time as "https://example.com":

```
<?php
```

session_start();

$_SESSION['client_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `function_exists( 'wp_validate_redirect' )` isn't very likely to be true, in a script _outside_ of your Wordpress code. And the referrer is simply unreliable, that is a well known fact - user agents might not send it due to privacy concerns. You could either try to "bootstrap Wordpress" (include the loader for the core functionality), if your contact form script is on the same server, under the same domain; otherwise, you will probably have to pass the URL as a GET parameter in the places where you are linking to the contact form script.

Comment: The form is not in Wordpress and is on a different server.  It is on a different domain also.  I will try GET.  Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that solved my issue.

In the original URL page, I changed the a tag to include the `client_url=(the page url).`

In the `index.php` (1st page of the form), I added the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['client_url'])) {

$cu = $_GET['client_url'];

}

$_SESSION['cu'] = $_GET['client_url'];

echo $cu; // to verify the URL is being captured
```

Then in the body of the form I added the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="client_url" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cu']; ?>">
```